# PowerBI Chart - Respond to one Filter but not to other

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have small situation here in PowerBI Report. I have a measure (lets called it as DistinctStudents) which gives me distinct records of a column of table.
I have two separate filters, one for Year and other for months.

What I want to achieve is to show DistinctStudents for that year selection. Please keep in mind that there is a filter for month as well which is used for other visuals.

How do it make sure that chart reacts to Year filter but not on Month filter?
Also, if previous Year is selected, I need to show all months for that year otherwise, start from January of current year till current month.

Comment: [ALL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax)

Comment: so should I create a new measure only for this chart? I want this chart to react to all the additional filters except that of month..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this one.. Small thing.. I had to use Edit Interactions.